# Moveit on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: moveit, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
we would like to use Moveit on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The only officially supported ROS version for this release is Kinetic Kame, but Moveit is only really available for Indigo.
Will there be any kinetic-moveit packages soon? If not, what would be the best way to get Moveit running on 16.04?
Best Regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235961/moveit-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [Nicolas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4738/nicolas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Nicolas, you can check the status of packages here [kineticPlanningMaintenance](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Planning/Maintenance). You could also create an issue on their [github issues page](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues) (I don't know if that is the right approach). It also looks like they have a kinetic-devel for their moveit_core branch, you could try to  [check that out](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/tree/kinetic-devel) as well.

---

Originally posted by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) with karma: 136 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-06-03**:
This is all right approach; so far there's no option to use MoveIt! on Kinetic other than building from source. MoveIt! maintenance team is under restructuring and I assume it may take awhile before it'll be released.

**Comment by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) on 2016-06-03**:
That's good to know! I found their [blog](http://moveit.ros.org/blog/) but the last update is from 2015. Do they update somewhere else?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-06-03**:
Not that I know of other than the blog you mentioned and [the email forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/moveit-users).